# Realloc to read in a big text file in C

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

I'm trying to read in a big text file and strcpy/strcat it into an array.

I have a simple program:

```
char buffer[500000];
char *text;
text = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1);
strcpy(text,"");

while (fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fp) != NULL)
{
    text = realloc(text,sizeof(char) * strlen(buffer));
    strcat(text,buffer);
    printf("%s",text);
}
```

The problem is that eventually after alot of iterations it will crash but I'm not sure why. I tried to do

```
text = realloc(text,sizeof(char) * strlen(buffer) + sizeof(text));
```

but this doesnt work either.

Comment: It is tempting to do `text = realloc(text, newsize);` but it's a potential memory leak.

Comment: `sizeof(text)` is pointer size, not contents size. You need `stelen(text)+strlen(buffer)+1` as new size.

Comment: Am I missing something? You realloc everytime to the size of the buffer. You are never adding to the realloc size, always just the size of the buffer you just read...

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, I can't see `sizeof(text)`

Comment: That's not a program. It is not even a function.

Comment: Also It is better to record it as cumulative size than to calculate the size each time. E.g `size_t newsize = 1;...newsize += strlen(buffer);.. text = realloc(text, newsize);`

Comment: @ArmenB Use Ctrl+F

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, oh the second part sorry.

Comment: @FreeStyle4, try checking for null when returning from realloc.

Comment: The `strcat` writes out of bounds of what you allocated. Recheck your math

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the `strlen(buffer)` size is zero at which case realloc might return a point to NULL. 
To be safe check of NULL when returning from realloc, and even maybe check the length of buffer before calling realloc.